# Recursion and Xcode 7 compile error

Tags: xcode, swift, recursion, swift2

this is a simple recursion function

```
func recursion(parameter : Double)
{
    if parameter < 12
    {
        recursion(parameter + 1)
    }
    print(parameter)
}
```

when i am trying to put a simple value for example 0 or 1

```
recursion(0)
```

i get a compile error saying Missing argument for #1 in call any idea why this is happening?

btw if i change the function to

```
func recursion(parameter : Double)
{
    if parameter > 1
    {
        recursion(parameter - 1)
    }
    print(parameter)
}
```

everything works fine

any ideas? i am using Xcode 7 beta

Comment: A *runtime* error or a *compile-time* error?

Comment: compile time error. I mistyped there :P

Comment: Where are you testing your code? It's work fine in XCode 7 Beta 6 using playgrounds

Comment: i am using the same beta as you xCode 7 beta 6.. But i am getting that exactly error i am trying with the first fund although it does show up the numbers in correct order so it seems to be more of a display bug (?)

Comment: if i simple change the function parameter from type Double to Int seems to fix that displaying problem but it's kinda lame. Also when i did try to call the function with a parameter something Double (ex : 1.1, 2.3 or w/e) some times it did give me some compile errors such as can't use . as postfix. IDK what's wrong but do you guys happen to get any of these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine, just make a `Clean & Build` and then try it again and the initial compile error should disappear. Remember that Xcode 7 is still in Beta, Apple is working to fix this kind of false compile errors properly.

I hope this help you.